# Android - How to get Inapp purchase order details?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-developers-console, google-play-developer-api

On the server side, I need to verify an In-app purchase and get details of the order. For the first part, I can verify an In-app purchase via https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get this API call and get an order-id.

However, I could not find a way to get order details which include total invoiced amount, tax amount and the estimated revenue. I can see these details from Google Play Developer Console. I need to make a dashboard in which these pieces of information will be reported to our suppliers. Therefore I cannot use  Developer Console and need an API endpoint to get these data.

Is there such an endpoint to get order details of an in-app purchase?

Comment: 6 months and no reply ... did you figure it out? If so, maybe you can reply to your own question. I would be interested to know how to fetch this as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are APIs to download reports from Google Cloud Storage. The [help page is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870).